# How to pass the text within an anchor tag to the controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am very beginner MVC. I have a view to update the user profile and I used some JavaScript Functions to edit the text

```
<p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><a style="padding-left:0.5em;" href="#" id="inline-username" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-title="Edit Phone #">@Model.Phone</a></p>
```

I need to get the text after editing just to update the Model.Phone value, so how do i pass the text inside the anchor tag to the action?
Here is my Action header

```
public ActionResult DashPersonalProfile(useracount acc, HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You could retreive the text value using jQuery and then use AJAX to call your action. Have you tried that?

Comment: I tried to to use Ajax but it didn't work and actually I am not familliar with jQuery and Ajax @DanielShillcock

Comment: many thanks to you :) I hope this will help @DanielShillcock